# Julia 1.4.1 fail to start, but 1.3.1 not. What is the issue?

Tags: linux, compilation, runtime, julia

Julia 1.3.1 works fine in my ubuntu 18.04 platform:

```
Linux KenServ 5.3.0-45-generic #37~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 27 15:58:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But when I download and try to run julia 1.4.1 it fails and show me this messages:

```
Invalid instruction at 0x7faf524e39f8: 0x66, 0x0f, 0x3a, 0x0f, 0xc0, 0x08, 0x0f, 0x83, 0x61, 0x05, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0xc1, 0xe0

signal (4): Instrucción ilegal
in expression starting at none:0
_ZN4llvm13LexicalScopes23assignInstructionRangesERNS_15SmallVectorImplISt4pairIPKNS_12MachineInstrES5_EEERNS_8DenseMapIS5_PNS_12LexicalScopeENS_12DenseMapInfoIS5_EENS_6detail12DenseMapPairIS5_SB_EEEE at /home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/bin/../lib/julia/libLLVM-8jl.so (unknown line)
_ZN4llvm13LexicalScopes10initializeERKNS_15MachineFunctionE at /home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/bin/../lib/julia/libLLVM-8jl.so (unknown line)
_ZN4llvm18LiveDebugVariables20runOnMachineFunctionERNS_15MachineFunctionE at /home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/bin/../lib/julia/libLLVM-8jl.so (unknown line)
_ZN4llvm19MachineFunctionPass13runOnFunctionERNS_8FunctionE at /home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/bin/../lib/julia/libLLVM-8jl.so (unknown line)
_ZN4llvm13FPPassManager13runOnFunctionERNS_8FunctionE at /home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/bin/../lib/julia/libLLVM-8jl.so (unknown line)
_ZN4llvm13FPPassManager11runOnModuleERNS_6ModuleE at /home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/bin/../lib/julia/libLLVM-8jl.so (unknown line)
_ZN4llvm6legacy15PassManagerImpl3runERNS_6ModuleE at /home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/bin/../lib/julia/libLLVM-8jl.so (unknown line)
operator() at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/jitlayers.cpp:356
addModule at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/usr/include/llvm/ExecutionEngine/Orc/IRCompileLayer.h:84 [inlined]
addModule at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/jitlayers.cpp:485
jl_add_to_ee at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/jitlayers.cpp:747 [inlined]
jl_finalize_function at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/jitlayers.cpp:755
getAddressForFunction at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:1414
jl_generate_fptr at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/codegen.cpp:1508
jl_compile_method_internal at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:1912
_jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2153 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2322
#764 at ./client.jl:370
jfptr_#764_8156 at /home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/lib/julia/sys.so (unknown line)
_jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2144 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2322
jl_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/julia.h:1700 [inlined]
do_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/builtins.c:643
jl_f__apply_latest at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/builtins.c:693
#invokelatest#1 at ./essentials.jl:712 [inlined]
invokelatest at ./essentials.jl:711 [inlined]
run_main_repl at ./client.jl:367
exec_options at ./client.jl:305
_start at ./client.jl:484
jfptr__start_2075 at /home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/lib/julia/sys.so (unknown line)
_jl_invoke at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2144 [inlined]
jl_apply_generic at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/src/gf.c:2322
jl_apply at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/ui/../src/julia.h:1700 [inlined]
true_main at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/ui/repl.c:96
main at /buildworker/worker/package_linux64/build/ui/repl.c:217
__libc_start_main at /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (unknown line)
_start at ./julia (unknown line)
Allocations: 2505 (Pool: 2496; Big: 9); GC: 0
Instrucción ilegal (`core' generado)
```

I try to compile from source. The same thing happens.

```
Invalid instruction at 0x7fad3a976ad0: 0x66, 0x0f, 0x3a, 0x0f, 0xc0, 0x08, 0x0f, 0x83, 0xae, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x48, 0xc1, 0xe0
signal (4): Instrucción ilegal

Allocations: 1 (Pool: 1; Big: 0); GC: 0
Illegal instruction (core dumped)
*** This error might be fixed by running `make clean`. If the error persists, try `make cleanall`. ***
sysimage.mk:67: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo '/home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/usr/lib/julia/sys.ji'
make[1]: *** [/home/kenneth/Descargas/julia/julia-1.4.1/usr/lib/julia/sys.ji] Error 1
Makefile:81: fallo en las instrucciones para el objetivo 'julia-sysimg-ji'
make: *** [julia-sysimg-ji] Error 2
```

Please help me, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/35215. You can probably(?) build from source by setting `override USE_BINARYBUILDER=0` in a `Make.user` file and rerun `make`.

Comment: Thank you @fredrikekre, but I try to compile with your recomendation. Still fails. My cpu is; `model name : AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor`. I'm using gcc verrsion `gcc (Ubuntu 8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04) 8.4.0`  I use this Make.user file also:  MARCH=amdfam10
OPENBLAS_TARGET_ARCH=NEHALEM
USE_BINARYBUILDER=0
OPENBLAS_USE_THREAD=0
It does not work either. What else can I do?

Comment: I got an update of the issue. I install a clean and new ubuntu. I install ubuntu 20.04. And now all julia versions works fine, 1.3.1, 1.4.1, and the dev version 1.5 also. So, is it really an AMD processor issue?